# Are hotel beds rated?

Tags: hotels, sleeping

Is there any kind of bed rating system for hotels?

I would like to only rent at hotels with extremely firm mattresses. It seems to be nearly 100% hit or miss. I've stayed at hotels expensive hotels with very soft mattresses (and therefore horrible for bad backs) and I've stayed an inexpensive hotels with mattresses that are just fine. And of course visa versa.

I'd like to know 3 things

1. Is there any kind of mattress rating system for customers so for example I could ask the hotel, "are your beds rated ___"
2. Is there any kind of industry standard for hotel management. As in is it mostly just up to a random interior designer or is there some standard hotel designers follow?
3. Are there more than ratings than just soft -> firm. For example some beds feels firm to the touch but bow in the middle as though the mattress as no support underneath. Like a hammock. Where as you can have a soft bed that doesn't bow. I prefer firm to soft but more importantly I prefer flat to bowing.

Comment: If the hotel is expensive enough they will bring in the mattress you need, but you may not want to pay that kind of hotel charges.

Comment: Not sure what you consider expensive. I'm curious why all hotels or all high end wouldn't  opt for firm with removable padding. They can pad up for guests that want soft and remove padding for guests that want firm. Where as soft beds can not be made firm

Comment: I was thinking of the top of the range hotels I recently saw on TV, with rooms from 400 to 10 000 UK pound per night. And likely this kind of service will not be available for the 'cheaper' rooms.

Comment: Hilton Garden Inn hotels used to use a mattress with adjustable firmness, however they seem to have phased those out over the past few years.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any universal ranking system for mattress in the hospitality industry. Different corporations or chains may chose to have their own rating (and they are NOT committed to any standard).

If you are willing to risk your patience, you are advised to consider the [Mattress Firmness Guide](https://www.sleeplikethedead.com/mattress-firmness.html) from "sleep like the dead" at your next hotel stay.

I had back issues and am Morbidly Obese, so I always asked the reservation clerks for a "Hard" mattress - and the results differ... In Japan, one hotel (its name escapes me) had six levels to choose from (Very Soft, Soft, Hard with a comfort layer, Hard, Very Hard) - but actually it was either soft or hard.

hih